# Domain registrars supporting wildcard CNAME records

Tags: domain, domain-registration, wildcard-subdomain

Please list some credible domain registrars supporting wildcard domains. Now I am with GoDaddy, and want to move to another one with the feature I need. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean a host? Registrars done have anything to do with DNS.

Comment: I am developing a GAE application and want users have their own subdomains. So, the only thing I need is to create a wildcard cname record like *.mydomain.com to use it with my app.

Comment: That is a function of DNS, not the registrar. All that a registrar does is sell you the domain name. Some companies like GoDaddy can offer additional services, such as DNS and hosting, but that is totally separate from their operation as a registrar.

Comment: +1 for MarkM. The services you need are not the responsibility of the registrar. The service that you need is DNS which can be addon.

Answer (score 1):

Any decent DNS host is going to allow this, for example http://www.easydns.com

Comment: This isn't a registrar issue as many have pointed out: Your DNS provider (*not* the domain registrar, although the two are often the same these days) is what needs to be changed here.  EasyDNS is one possibility; Hosting your own DNS server is another...

Comment: Since he doesn't seem entirely sure of the distinction between the registrar and the DNS host, I wouldn't really recommend that he host his own DNS.